# Parsing unregistered options for config files in Boost program_options?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options, configuration-files

With command line options, I can do the following:

```
po::variables_map vm;
auto parsedOptions = po::command_line_parser(argc, argv).options(optionsDescription1).allow_unregistered().run();
po::store(parsedOptions, vm);
po::notify(vm);

auto unregistered = po::collect_unrecognized(parsedOptions.options, po::include_positional);
po::variables_map vm2;
auto parsedOptions2 = po::command_line_parser(unregistered).options(optionsDescription2).run();
po::store(parsedOptions2, vm2);
po::notify(vm2);
```

This works fine, because `collect_unregistered()` collects the command line tokens exactly as it appeared in the command line. However, it doesn't work for config files. I can parse a config file allowing unregistered options, but when I collect the unregistered options, I get a result that I cannot use.

```
po::variables_map vm;
auto parsedOptions = po::parse_config_file<char>(filename, optionsDescription1, true);
po::store(parsedOptions, vm);
po::notify(vm);
auto unregistered = po::collect_unrecognized(parsedOptions.options, po::include_positional);
```

In this case I get the names and values of the options listed. For example, if the config file contained the following options:

```
unregistered_option1=value1
unregistered_option2=value2
```

Then I get the values `unregistered_option1`, `value1`, `unregistered_option2`, `value2` in the string vector `unregistered`. Boost's parser cannot do anything useful with this format. Is there any way to parse this list (i.e. parse all the options that were unrecognized by the first `options_description` with a different `options_description`)? Of course I can just parse the file again with the second `options_description` with `allow_unregistered` set, but then I can't check for options unknown to both descriptions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to rely on the imperfections of `collect_unrecognized()` return value, you can always detect, handle and reconstruct the options yourself, as the result of `parse_config_file()` keeps the observed relationship for the unknown options:

```
auto parsed_options = parse_config_file(ifs, config_file_options, true);
store(parsed_options, vm);
...
for (const auto& o : parsed_options.options) {
    if (vm.find(o.string_key) == vm.end()) {
        // an unknown option
        cout << o.string_key << "=" << o.value << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know since when but there's now a `.unregistered` bool data member in the individual options that are looped over. So no need to search all of `vm` to find out if it was unregistered anymore.

Comment: Could you explain the vm.end() iterator line a bit? I don't think variables_map contains an  .end iterator?